# How to make a circular animation of wheel type?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to make a circular animation of just like this: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/circle-whos-around-you/id488720081?mt=8

Basically use scrolling on people showing on.. see attach file

Comment: May [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/CDPieMenu) will help you

Comment: @Aalok thanks for giving me this link

Comment: , @user1118231 yeah I tried so far but I am facing many problems in it...